# Noetherian vector space is finite-dimensional

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian

Given a field $k$, and a $k$-vector space $V$ which is noetherian as $k$-module, I want to show that $V$ is finite-dimensional.

Is it correct that this follows because since $V$ is noetherian, every submodule of $V$ is finitely generated as $k$-module, in particular $V$ itself, and hence $V$ is already a finite dimensional vector space?

I'm asking because I've seen another proof which looks more complicated, and I want to know whether my simple approach above is right.

Comment: Could you be more specific about this other proof? I think you're right.

Comment: @Hoot: I guess it's ‘in particular’.

Comment: which is the source where you have seen another proof?

Comment: This depends on the definition  you have for `noetherian`.

Comment: @Hoot The other proof is by contraposition. It's not really that complicated though. If $V$ was infinite-dimensional, one can pick some infinite basis $\{x_1,x_2,...\}$ and construct an infinite chain $<x_1>\subsetneq<x_1,x_2>\subsetneq<x_1,x_2,x_3>...$ which never becomes stationary, hence $V$ is not noetherian.

Comment: @Bernard Every submodule is finitely generated, or the ascending chain condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a vector space, having finite dimension is the same as being finitely generated.

One direction is obvious: if the vector space has a finite basis it clearly is finitely generated.

Suppose $V$ is finitely generated. From any finite spanning set $S$, one can extract a minimal spanning set $B$, in the sense that $B\subseteq S$ is a spanning set and no proper subset of $B$ is a spanning set. Prove that $B$ is linearly independent, hence a basis.

If $V$ is noetherian as a module, then it is finitely generated (along with all of its submodules).

---

If you don't know or can't use the characterization that a module is noetherian if and only if every submodule is finitely generated, but you can only use the ascending chain condition, you can do it in the following way.

Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional. Then no infinite chain of subspaces can exist, because if $U_1$ is a proper subspace of $U_2$, then $\dim U_1<\dim U_2$.

Assume $V$ is not finite dimensional, which means that no linearly independent finite set spans $V$. Then you can build inductively a chain of subspaces in the following way: since $V\ne\{0\}$, there is $v_1\in V$, $v_1\ne0$.

Assume you have found a linearly independent set $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$; then there is $v_{k+1}\in V\setminus\langle v_1,\dots,v_k\rangle$ and the set $\{v_1,\dots,v_k,v_{k+1}\}$ is again linearly independent. Then you have the infinite ascending chain
$$
\langle v_1\rangle \subsetneq
\langle v_1,v_2\rangle \subsetneq
\dots\subsetneq
\langle v_1,\dots,v_k\rangle \subsetneq
\langle v_1,\dots,v_k,v_{k+1}\rangle \subsetneq\dotsb
$$
and $V$ is not noetherian.

Comment: 'Suppose $V$ is finitely generated. From any finite spanning set $S$, one can extract a minimal spanning set $B$, in the sense that $B\subseteq S$ is a spanning set and no proper subset of $B$ is a spanning set. Prove that $B$ is linearly independent, hence a basis.' This is what I overlooked, so my approach would take longer after all if written out explicitly. Thank you for showing me.